# JMS Outbound Gateway does not work for request-channel: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am working with Spring Integration `'4.2.5.RELEASE'`

I have the following scenario (*experiment purposes*) for a global flow integration process

- Receive Data from a JMS Destination and send a reply
- Do something with the data received
- Send some data to a JMS Destination and receive a reply

About the two first points I have the following:

```
<!-- From Remote To Local -->           

<int:channel id="requestFromRemoteToLocalChannel" 
             datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" />

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="responseFromRemoteToLocalChannel" 
                               datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" />

<!-- From Local To Remote -->   

<int:channel id="requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel"                       
             datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" />

<int:channel id="responseFromLocalToRemoteChannel" 
             datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" />

<int:channel id="responseFromLocalToRemoteChannelPost" 
             datatype="com.manuel.jordan.message.Message" />

<int-jms:inbound-gateway 
         id="gatewayIn"
         request-destination="queueDestinationFromRemoteToLocal"
         default-reply-destination="queueDestinationFromRemoteToLocalReply"                          
         connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration"
         request-channel="requestFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
         reply-channel="responseFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
/>
```

followed with two services activators

```
<int:service-activator 
     id="serviceActivatorReceptorFromRemoteToLocal"
     input-channel="requestFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
     output-channel="responseFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
     ref="messageServerReceptorJmsGatewayEndpoint"
     method="receptorFromRemoteToLocal"
                            >
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator 
     id="serviceActivatorRemoveReplyFromRemoteToLocal"
     input-channel="responseFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
     output-channel="nullChannel"
     ref="messageServerReceptorJmsGatewayEndpoint"
     method="removeReplyFromRemoteToLocal"
                           >
</int:service-activator>
```

Until here all work fine.

Through a `JmsTemplate` I send data to the `queueDestinationFromRemoteToLocal` Destination and therefore the `int-jms:inbound-gateway` through the `request-destination` which points to the same Destination is able to automatically get the Message and pass it to a service activator and *send* a reply to other JMS destination and some `@JmsListener` does its job.

Again until here I am Ok..

The problem is when from this latest service activator I want send some data to a `int-jms:outbound-gateway`. It to accomplish the third point of the global integration process

Just changing the latest service activator to:

```
<int:service-activator 
     id="serviceActivatorRemoveReplyFromRemoteToLocal"
     input-channel="responseFromRemoteToLocalChannel"
     output-channel="requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel"
     ref="messageServerReceptorJmsGatewayEndpoint"
     method="removeReplyFromRemoteToLocal"
                           >            
</int:service-activator>
```

Practically from `output-channel="nullChannel"` to `output-channel="requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel"`

And adding:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway 
         id="gatewayOut"
         request-destination="queueDestinationFromLocalToRemote"                              
         reply-destination="queueDestinationFromLocalToRemoteReply"
         connection-factory="selectedConnectionFactory"
         correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
         explicit-qos-enabled="true"                        
         delivery-persistent="true"     
         auto-startup="false"               
         request-channel="requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel"
         reply-channel="responseFromLocalToRemoteChannel"

                              >
    <int-jms:reply-listener />

</int-jms:outbound-gateway> 

<int:service-activator 
     id="serviceActivatorRemoveReplyFromLocalToRemote"
     input-channel="responseFromLocalToRemoteChannel"
     output-channel="nullChannel"
     ref="messageServerReceptorJmsGatewayEndpoint"
     method="removeReplyFromLocalToRemote"
                >

</int:service-activator>
```

Enabling:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.integration">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

I can see:

> 31634 [gatewayIn.container-1] DEBUG o.s.i.j.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@51565ec2.requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Practically the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` is *not* called

What is missing?

Even if I change the `requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel` from `Direct` to `Queue` and add a `poller` to the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` nothing happens, the message shown above disappears but the process remains hanged

**Note**: `int-jms:outbound-gateway` uses `auto-startup="false"` because the `connection-factory="selectedConnectionFactory"` (It is **non** cached) comes from:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(...);
connectionFactory.setClientID("localConnectionFactory");
connectionFactory.setUserName("Manolito - Local");
connectionFactory.createConnection().start();// By This...
connectionFactory.setExceptionListener(new ConnectionFactoryExceptionListener());
return connectionFactory;
```

other settings has been used according with: [20.5 Outbound Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway)

If I use:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(...);
connectionFactory.setClientID("localConnectionFactory");
connectionFactory.setUserName("Manolito - Local");
//connectionFactory.createConnection().start();
connectionFactory.setExceptionListener(new ConnectionFactoryExceptionListener());
return connectionFactory;
```

And `auto-startup="true"` (it is default anyway) I get:

> 24917 [gatewayIn.container-1] DEBUG o.s.i.j.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: localConnectionFactory already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:59497

*Alpha*

Adding a new

```
@Bean
@Conditional(value=ActiveMQConnectionFactoryLocalHostStatusCondition.class)
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration(
            @Value("${activemq.localhost.protocol}") String protocol,
            @Value("${activemq.localhost.address}") String host,
            @Value("${activemq.localhost.port}") String port) throws JMSException {

        logger.info("Creating localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration...");

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(sameUrl like localConnectionFactory);
        connectionFactory.setClientID("localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration");
        connectionFactory.setUserName("Manolito - Local ForSpringIntegration");
        //connectionFactory.createConnection().start();
        connectionFactory.setExceptionListener(new ConnectionFactoryExceptionListener());
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

Here, `setClientID` and `setUserName` are news and this `localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration` is used only for below:
`connection-factory="localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration"`

And changing

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway 
         id="gatewayOut"
         request-destination="queueDestinationFromLocalToRemote"                              
         reply-destination="queueDestinationFromLocalToRemoteReply"
         connection-factory="localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration"
         correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
         explicit-qos-enabled="true"                        
         delivery-persistent="true"     
         auto-startup="true"                

         request-channel="requestFromLocalToRemoteChannel"
         reply-channel="responseFromLocalToRemoteChannel"

                              >
    <int-jms:reply-listener />

</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

I get again:

> [gatewayIn.container-1] DEBUG o.s.i.j.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate - failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive: nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:50056

Until here:

- I have `localConnectionFactory` and `localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration` pointing to the same `BrokerURL`
- `int-jms:outbound-gateway` needs a non-cached `connection-factory`
- `localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration` has commented `connectionFactory.createConnection().start()`
- `int-jms:outbound-gateway` has `auto-startup="true"`

Seems in some point `localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration` has been started and the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` throws:

> localhost - Client: localConnectionFactoryForSpringIntegration already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:50056

Seems something is needed it

Answer (score 0):

Consuming endpoints don't subscribe to a direct channel (or poll from a queue channel) until they are started. Hence dispatcher has no subscribers when the gateway is in a stopped state (or nothing polled from the queue).

> InvalidClientIDException

You can't create multiple connections with the same client id; if you use different connection factories, they need unique client ids.

Comment: Thanks by the reply, pls check new content added in _Alpha_ section.

Comment: You generally don't need to start() the connection - the framework will do so when needed. If you can post your project somewhere I can take a look.

Comment: Sorry by my delay. Let me do a heavy refactoring (I am in this process, now I am working with two `ActiveMQ` instances in the same server/machine), perhaps I can find what is wrong, otherwise I will do your suggestion. Thanks